# Why would anyone use JSON for data transferral to a Java server?

Tags: javascript, java, json, server, client

A big curiosity to me is why so many people like to go through the hassle of creating JSON files, writing objects into it, and having a server somewhere access that file and use a java-json library to read and parse the data when you can alternatively put all the objects you're sending into a string which separates keys/values by appropriate characters and send that mere string which the server parses.

Example, on the JavaScript side:

```
function convertToSendableString(object) {

  if (object instanceof Array){
  var stringToSend = "";
   for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
   stringToSend += object[i] + "~";
   }
  }

  if (object instanceof Object){
  //Do something similar as what was done with Array but add another
  //character to separate each key/value pair. ex. 
  //car~honda*book~dictionary*sanity~almostgone*
  } 

return stringToSend;
}

client.write(convertToSendableString(someObject));
```

And then on the server side (in this case, in Java):

```
is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((DataInputStream) is));

 String line = "";

                try {
                    while (in.ready()) {
                        char character = (char) in.read();    
                        line = line + character;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

String[] parts = line.split("*");
...
```

And so on... As long as you put enough care to forbid the use of those characters elsewhere in your program, why would you want to complicate things to the extreme that modern data transferral has done?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Well... maybe it is more easier and faster to create an object, stringify it with `JSON.stringify()` than making a "non-standar" format that only the developers know... I think is better to have a standarized format than letting anyones format the information in whatever way they want... It is more easier to another developer to understand what happens.

Comment: One of the issues with web design is that there are so many platforms to work with that developers are regularly thrown into situations where they know some things very well, and others not so well.  In that situation, developers tend to reduce the learning curve as far as possible, and wind up going with what they know.  On the other hand, standards such as JSON are there in part to reduce development overhead.  If I can do your example in my sleep, or spend two days making sure that there are no problems with your alternative that I'm not familiar with, I'm going to go with your example.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my experience, i would not choose my own format for data if it is a project that goes beyond my personal use or experimentation. Better to use a standar that anyone knows (or can understand very quickly), which also have lots of libraries out there, and is a well-tested format for situations that maybe you don't know that can occur, saving you possible headaches.

If you don't have a solid argument for saying "let's use this format instead of this", i would go for a standar format like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding Various encoding formats:

What it sounds like you're describing is a special character separated format. CSVs (Comma Separated Values) are popular for datasets where column names will be the same throughout the data. However, if you are transmitting data from the server to the client containing nested objects or an object containing lists, it is difficult to clearly represent this in such a fashion.

You could use JSON for these tasks and a CSV for others, however using one standard system for your entire API will make it MUCH easier for both yourself and later developers looking at your project as there is only one format to worry about (Limiting things to go wrong).

## Okay, so lets come up with our own standard:

> put all the objects you're sending into a string which separates keys/values by appropriate characters and send that mere string which the server parses.

Okay, so we start off with something like this (your example):

```
car~honda*book~dictionary*sanity~almostgone*
```

Later on, however, we decide that sometimes we want to serve multiple objects in one response, using newlines.

```
car~honda*book~dictionary*sanity~almostgone*
car~flintstonemobile*book~thesaurus*sanity~beengoneforawhile*
```

Perhaps though we should describe the cars with the name, miles per gallon, and wheel count within the response too.

```
car~!name~honda*mpg~16*wheels~4!*book~dictionary*sanity~almostgone*
car~!name~flintstonemobile*mpg~0*wheels~2!*book~thesaurus*sanity~beengoneforawhile*
```

By the time you've added in functionality for different data types and lists, you end up with something not too different from JSON:

- ~ --> :
- ! --> {}
- * --> ,

For comparison: (though you'd need to "" your strings)

```
{car:{name:honda,mpg:16,wheels:4},book:dictionary,sanity:almostgone}
```

In the end, yes you could optimize your bandwidth through custom formatting, tricky encoding, and some math. However using a standard such as JSON should not only make it more readable for other programmers but also easier to code as there are a plethora of JSON serializers/interpreters.

- It should also be noted that newlines are probably not supported in query parameters by all browsers, so you'd have to restructure your encoding closer to JSON's list format anyway.